# Xcode 4 and Snow Leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, mac-appstore, software-update, xcode

This is the thing :

- I have Xcode 4.3 on my MacBook Pro (running Lion)
- I am stuck with 4.0.2 on my iMac (running Snow Leopard)

Given that I would really like to retain a SnowLeopard-running machine (for development purposes), is there any way I could get anything 4.1 or above, to run on my iMac?

Comment: Is it possible that the command line tools for 10.6.8 are not longer available on the apple developer center?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have registered for the paid iOS developer program, you should be able to see Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard available in the [iOS Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).

Here's what I see from a paid account:

[image: Xcode paid developer account]

Here's what I see from a non-paid account (there's no Xcode 4.x for Snow Leopard):

[image: Xcode non-paid developer account]

This also explains why Xcode is a paid download in the Snow Leopard App Store, but is free in the Lion App Store.

Comment: I am registered iOS and Mac developer, but I still cannot find any link for Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard (is it even supported? I am not 100% sure). All I found is for Lion. Any ideas or specific links to point me to?

Comment: Have you paid the yearly $99 fee?

Comment: Of course I have. http://itunes.apple.com/gr/artist/insili.co/id450339436?mt=12

Comment: That's REALLY REALLY weird. How is this : I am seeing the second page you posted... :-S

Comment: I think there are separate Developer Programs for iOS and OS X, are you sure you've paid for the right one?

Comment: OK, OK. I just figured out what was going wrong. Pretty stupid of me. You were 100% right. I was just logged in with the first-first username I was using (a tiny variation of it actually, too unnoticeable...) before being registered in the paid programs. (As for the Developer Programs, yep; they are separate; 99$/year each. I am registered for both of them, although I'm mainly a Mac developer.) Thanks A LOT! :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!

Comment: Well, I'm using my MacBook for Lion-testing and my iMac for SnowLeopard-testing, so it's quite a relief I will now be able to get a little bit up-to-date with my iMac machine as well. Thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you don’t really need Xcode, but all you need are the Xcode command line tools, [here’s how to install them on Snow Leopard](http://kitcambridge.tumblr.com/post/17778742499/installing-the-xcode-command-line-tools-on-snow-leopard).

Simply download the “Command Line Tools” package from [Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com/downloads) (free account required; you can use your Apple ID). As of this writing, the package is named “Command Line Tools for Xcode - Late March 2012”. It’s a 171.70 MB disk image, which pales in contrast to the 4+ GB full Xcode download.

Note that, if you’ve already installed Xcode, you’ll want to uninstall it before installing the Command Line Tools.

Once you’ve downloaded the package, launch Terminal.app and type:

```
cd
mkdir osx-gcc
cd /Volumes/Command\ Line\ Tools
cp -r * ~/osx-gcc

cd ~/osx-gcc
mkdir pkg
mv Command\ Line\ Tools.mpkg pkg/install.mpkg
cd pkg
xar -xvf install.mpkg
```

Note: It’s important that you use `cp -r`, rather than simply `cp`; the former will copy all hidden installation files to the `~/osx-gcc` directory. The `Command Line Tools.mpkg` file is merely a 512 KB descriptor that contains the installation instructions; the actual packages are located in the hidden, aptly-named `Packages` directory.

Next, open the `Distribution` file with your favorite text editor. I prefer TextMate (`mate Distribution`), but you can use `vi`, `emacs`, BBEdit, TextWrangler, or even TextEdit (`open -a TextEdit Distribution`). On the tenth line, you should see the following:

```
var majorOSVersion = '10.7';
```

This specifies the minimum operating system requirement — OS X 10.7 Lion, in this case. Change `'10.7'` to `'10.6'`, save the file, and close your text editor. You’ve now modified the package so that it will install successfully on Snow Leopard; the final step is to recreate the package file so that it can be read by the installer app:

```
rm install.mpkg
xar -c . -vf ../install.mpkg
cd ..
open install.mpkg
```

Answer (score 0):

After logging into the mac dev center, the "OS X Lion" homepage has a link near the bottom "Additional Downloads" with the description "Find additional pre-release software, previous versions of Mac OS X, and hardware driver downloads in the Apple Developer Downloads site."

Clicking the View All Downloads link takes me to a list of >150 downloads, sorted by date, and a category search.

In the Developer Tools category, click the "next page" link until you get to **Xcode  for Snow Leopard**.

Note I found it in the Mac Dev Center, I didn't check the iOS Dev Center, though I suspect the download might be there as well.